# Angular/Ionic4 How to send an sms without opening native sms App

Tags: angular, typescript, sms, ionic4

So I have been following the github repo(https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin) for the Ionic Native SMS plugin,
and I have configured as to the repo suggests with:

```
var options = {
            replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
            android: {
                intent: 'INTENT'  // send SMS with the native android SMS messaging
                //intent: '' // send SMS without opening any other app
            }
        };
```

however, when I test it on a real device, it still does not send a SMS.

can anyone help me, do I need to add in a permission?
Here is the code that I have so far

```
 sendSms() {
    let options = {
      replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
      android: {
          intent: ''  // send SMS with the native android SMS messaging
          // intent: '' // send SMS without opening any other app
      }
  };
    this.sms.send('656225667', 'SMS Works', options).then(val => {
      alert('It works');
    });
  }
```

Comment: Sending sms from your app without opening default sms app is against Google play policy

Comment: okay I am building an app that has a panic button and I want it to send an sms when the user taps on it, how would I achieve that, I dont want the user to press the button and then press send on the native sms app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send an SMS without opening the native SMS app.
you need to use Android Permission to get the SMS Permissions

**use these two function**

```
checkSMSPermission() {
  this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.SEND_SMS).then(
    result => console.log('Has permission?', result.hasPermission),
    err => this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.SEND_SMS)
  );
}
requestSMSPermission() {
  // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
  this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.SEND_SMS, this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.BROADCAST_SMS]);
}
```

**and you need to include these functions in the Android Manifest aswell.**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

**and then the SMS function itself**

```
sendSMS() {
  this.checkSMSPermission();
  this.contactComponent.getContact();
  const numberOne = this.contactComponent.mContacts[0].number;
  const numberTwo = this.contactComponent.mContacts[1].number;
  const numbeThree = this.contactComponent.mContacts[2].number;
  const numberFour = this.contactComponent.mContacts[3].number;
  const numberFive = this.contactComponent.mContacts[4].number;
  console.log(numberOne);

  // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
  const message = this.messageComponent.dangerMessage + ' my location is: lat: ' + this.latitude.toString() + 'lng: ' + this.longitude.toString();
  console.log('number=' + numberOne + ', message= ' + message);

  // CONFIGURATION
  const options = {
      replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
      android: {
          intent: ''  // send SMS with the native android SMS messaging
          // intent: '' // send SMS without opening any other app
      }
  };
  this.sms.send(numberOne, message, options).then(() => {
    this.presentAlert('Success', 'message has been sent');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.presentAlert('Error', 'Failed: ' + error);
  });
}
```

Comment: just a question where exactly put the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" /> I get a error if I am using the config.xml. The other Manifest files get created automatically as far I know.

Comment: does this still work?

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending a SMS, you are creating an [`INTENT`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common) to send a SMS.

> An intent allows you to start an activity in another app by describing
>   a simple action you'd like to perform (such as "view a map" or "take a
>   picture") in an Intent object. This type of intent is called an
>   implicit intent because it does not specify the app component to
>   start, but instead specifies an action and provides some data with
>   which to perform the action.

this means the code only generates the 'intent', which is then passed to your phones default app, which handles it. How it handles the `intent` is only up to the app. There can even be multiple apps which can handle the `intent`, then the use gets a choose dialog. Your app has no control, when the SMS really gets send.

This is actually a good thing, so if you install any app, you can be sure, that it doesn't send a SMS to a subscription service and you pay 100 € phone bills.

Comment: So you are saying the APP itself does not send the SMS, it is being sent with an Intent through the phones native android SMS application?

Comment: So can I create an intent that will open the native app and automatically send the sms?

I want a user to press a panic button and send an sms to multiple numbers

Comment: You cannot do do that, for the above reasons. If you want that you have to go with @rtpHarry solution.